# Error in updating profile details - Invalid image type

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, images

I'm not able to update my profile details, each time I try to update, it throws an error

> "Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: Invalid image type"

though I'm not making any changes in my profile picture.

[image]

Comment: Is that a gif file?

Comment: @Tushar I don't remember. I added the profile pic years back and have not updated since then. I just wanted to add a website in the "Website" field.

Comment: I was just trying to add a gif like in the about me and this happened. I guess something is wrong at the server end, try again in a day or two.

Comment: Why this down vote?

Comment: Not me dude. I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Tushar I didn't mean it's you :) whoever has done this, I expect a reason.

Comment: People are free to vote however they like without providing reasons. Having said that, most likely they downvoted because they thought the question didn't provide enough information to reproduce the problem and/or they think the issue is not important. Remember that on Meta votes do not affect your reputation.

Comment: Same thing here

Comment: In my case theres no images involved, just tried editing 'About me' (no links). :/

Comment: There are some more people with this problem [in the post about the new user activity page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250160/241622) on meta.stackexchange. I, and others, get this error on other Stack Exchange sites as well. My image is a .jpg but there are users with PNG images at the linked post.

Comment: Temporarily switch to Gravatar, I have no issues with it to date.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal - just a note - if you add more relevant tags (not **just** bug), such issues would be easier for Stack Overflow developers to find...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was an change to how profile images were handled that broke the edit page for users with an uploaded profile image.

This is now fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Oded I'll surely try to add as much details as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem just now.

Went for updating the profile, edited/entered some text, error as in OPs description.

Uploaded the same picture that was already set, then it worked.

Comment: Same problem for me. **Quick fix:** I just selected change picture on my profile image, chose the Identicon, right away chose my already upload image, pressed save profile and it worked. *YAY*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even I found the same issue right now. I too tried to upload same image and yes it worked. Probably stackoverflow has issues with the references of locations. pointer to image is not working in update section.

Anyways, Solution is "Re-upload the Image" while editing the information.