# "Invalid image type" error when changing profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

So I'm trying to add my Twitter handle to my profile, and when I go to save what I just did, I'm greeted by this:

[image: annoying bug]

Which is weird considering that I already have a profile picture, and wasn't changing it (or doing anything related to images for that matter.)

(This seems to have been a problem before ([Error in updating profile details - Invalid image type](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286854/error-in-updating-profile-details-invalid-image-type)), that's been fixed, but somehow it has become unfixed)

Comment: No idea off-hand on what's busted, but here's a workaround: switch your profile image to something else, save, and then switch back. (I did that for your profile on SO, so you should be able to proceed with whatever other edits you want to do.)